# node.js - Dial to Number with Twilio

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, express, twilio

I'm building myself a click-to-call website that utilizes Twilio. After I configured in TwiML app and wrote Twilio JavaScript SDK client-side to make request to Twilio, then Twilio will make a `POST` request to this route of mine:

```
 app.post('/callcenter',function(req,res){    
    const twilio=require('twilio');
    var twiml=new twilio.TwimlResponse();
        res.type('text/xml');
        twiml.dial({},function(node){
            node.number('MY_PHONE_NUMBER');
        });
        res.send(twiml.toString());
 );
```

This is the most simplified use of `Dial` in REST API for TwiML that I want to respond to Twilio to make a call to `MY_PHONE_NUMBER`. But I always ended up hearing voice of `"An error occured..."`
Please someone help me point out what did I do wrong in this route handler? Server is built in ExpressJS

Comment: Can you check the logs at Twilio, can you get any hint from there?

Comment: @AlexBaban No, I couldn't

Comment: Use Fiddler http://www.telerik.com/fiddler , make a POST request to your resource. What is the response? Do you get the correct XML response, do you have the correct headers/content type? Twilio is just a client like a browser from this perspective.

Answer (score 1):

try this out:

```
twiml.dial({callerId : process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER}, MY_PHONE_NUMBER);
```

which comes from: https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/browser-calls/node/express 
There click to the page call.js.

Comment: Please check out the new twilio SDK